# filter invalid values in json string

Tags: c#, .net, json, nancy

I'm getting a string in a html body that I am trying to process into valid json. The string I receive isn't a valid json string and contains the following schema:

```
äÄ
    "key1": "  10",
    "key2": "beigef}gtem Zahlschein",
    "key3": "     G E L \ S C H T",
    "key4": "M}nchen",
    "key5": "M{rz",
    "key6": "[huus"
Ü
ä
```

I've written a function to replace all the faulty characters to create a valid json-string, but how do i do the reverse without destroying the letters needed in json?

This is how I replaced the characters:

```
private static string FixChars(string input)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            if (input.Contains("["))
            {
                input = input.Replace("[", "Ä");
            }
            if (input.Contains(@"\"))
            {
                input = input.Replace(@"\", "Ö");
            }
            if (input.Contains("]"))
            {
                input = input.Replace("]", "Ü");
            }
            if (input.Contains("{"))
            {
                input = input.Replace("{", "ä");
            }
            if (input.Contains("|"))
            {
                input = input.Replace("|", "ö");
            }
            if (input.Contains("}"))
            {
                input = input.Replace("}", "ü");
            }
            if (input.Contains("~"))
            {
                input = input.Replace("~", "ß");
            }
            //DS_Stern hat Probleme beim xml erstellen gemacht
            //if (input.Contains("*"))
            //{
            //    input = input.Replace("*", "Stern");
            //}
        }
        return input;
    }
```

Then I've tried to deserialize the json-array into an Dictionary like this:

```
deserializedRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(json);
```

How do I access the different dictionaries, use my FixChars-method on the values and reserialize a valid json-string from that?

EDIT: IBM273 and decoding via IBM037 works fine to create a valid json string, but still contains a minor error: the character 'ö' is '|' in that encoding.

Comment: It looks like you may have constructed the your `json` string from a steam using the wrong [encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377(v=vs.110).aspx).  The correct fix is to use the correct encoding.  How did you create the string?

Comment: I get the string from the body of a website provided by an old cobol-based machine

Comment: Maybe, possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36336493/c-sharp-cannot-create-ebcdic-file-on-unisys-mainframe-windows-share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though the HTML page containing your JSON was encoded into a byte stream on your *Unisys A-Series type of machine (cobol74)* using one [encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377(v=vs.110).aspx) and then decoded by your code using a different encoding, thereby causing some characters to get remapped or lost.  To fix your problem, you need to determine the original encoding used on that Unisys computer, and decode the HTML stream using it.  Making things a little more complicated is that we're not sure which encoding .Net chose to decode the HTML either.

One way to make the determination is to take a sample of the expected JSON, then encode it and decode it using all possible *pairs* of encodings available in .Net.  If any pair of encodings produces the incorrect results you are seeing, then the encoding used to encode the string may possibly be the one used on the Unisys computer.  And, by reversing the transformation you may be able to fix your string, assuming no characters were dropped.

The following code does this test:

```
var correctString = "{}[]";
var observedString = "äüÄÜ";

int count = 0;
foreach (var toEncoding in Encoding.GetEncodings())
    foreach (var fromEncoding in Encoding.GetEncodings())
    {
        var s = toEncoding.GetEncoding().GetString(fromEncoding.GetEncoding().GetBytes(correctString));
        if (s == observedString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Match Found: Encoding via {0} and decoding via {1}", fromEncoding.Name, toEncoding.Name));
            count++;
        }
    }
Console.WriteLine("Found {0} matches", count);
```

This produces 147 matches, including a bunch of pairs of [ebcdic](/questions/tagged/ebcdic) encodings.  For the full list see this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jXk3pA).

Next, let's try to cut down on the matches by testing the full JSON string:

```
var correctJson = @"{[
    ""key1"": ""  10"",
    ""key2"": ""beigefügtem Zahlschein"",
    ""key3"": ""     G E L Ö S C H T"",
    ""key4"": ""München"",
    ""key5"": ""März"",
    ""key6"": ""Ähuus"",
    ""key7"": ""ö"",
    ""key8"": ""ß"",
]
{";
var observedJson = @"äÄ
    ""key1"": ""  10"",
    ""key2"": ""beigef}gtem Zahlschein"",
    ""key3"": ""     G E L \ S C H T"",
    ""key4"": ""M}nchen"",
    ""key5"": ""M{rz"",
    ""key6"": ""[huus"",
    ""key7"": ""|"",
    ""key8"": ""~"",
Ü
ä";

int count = 0;
foreach (var toEncoding in Encoding.GetEncodings())
    foreach (var fromEncoding in Encoding.GetEncodings())
    {
        var s = toEncoding.GetEncoding().GetString(fromEncoding.GetEncoding().GetBytes(correctJson));
        if (s == observedJson)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Match Found: Encoding via {0} and decoding via {1}", fromEncoding.Name, toEncoding.Name));
            count++;
        }
    }
Console.WriteLine("Found {0} matches", count);
```

This produces just 2 EBCDIC matches:

```
Match Found: Encoding via IBM01141 and decoding via IBM870
Match Found: Encoding via IBM273 and decoding via IBM870
```

So one of these is almost certainly the correct pair of encodings.  But, which one?  According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_273):

> CCSID 1141 is the Euro currency update of code page/CCSID 273. In that code page, the "¤" (currency) character at code point 9F is replaced with the "€" (Euro) character.

So to narrow down the encoding to a single choice, you'll need to test a sample with the "€" character.

Then if I add the following extension method:

```
public static class TextExtensions
{
    public static string Reencode(this string s, Encoding toEncoding, Encoding fromEncoding)
    {
        return toEncoding.GetString(fromEncoding.GetBytes(s));
    }
}
```

I can fix your JSON by doing:

```
var fixedJson = observedJson.Reencode(Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM01141"), Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM870"));
Console.WriteLine(fixedJson);
```

Comment: var json = Request.Body.AsString(Encoding.GetEncoding(20106)); changed the characters as wanted but returns [,],{,} as '?'

Comment: @Zoba - What about `Request.Body.AsString(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"))`?  Also, what kind of "old cobol based machine" is this?  An IBM of some sort?

Comment: it returns 'Ää' in the front instead of [{ and the umlauts are wrong too. As far as I know something like a Unisys A-Series type of machine (cobol74)

Comment: It's not quite right, because key6 should be Ähuus. I'll look into the right one!

Comment: @Zoba - looks like transcoding between "IBM500" and "IBM273" does the job.  Note the JSON isn't valid -- it ends on a `{` not a `}`.  This is not an encoding problem since the first and last characters are both `ä`.

Comment: This has been extremly helpful and is what i was looking for. I'll try to get a dataset containing a € character and will update the post accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123516/discussion-between-zoba-and-dbc).