# C# UTF8 Encoding/Decoding issue

Tags: javascript, c#, encoding, utf-8

I have to read a bad encoded string from a remote service and can not figure out how to recover the correct value in C# or Javascript. I can neither change the values in the service or change the way they are being saved in the DB, but I need to display them correctly.

```
Bad string: AdriÃ¡n JosÃ©
Correct string: Adrián José
```

The error can be undone since the fixed value can be obtained using tools such as [https://www.iosart.com/tools/charset-fixer](https://www.iosart.com/tools/charset-fixer/?source-text=Adri%C3%83%C2%A1n+Jos%C3%83%C2%A9&input-encoding=UTF-8) or in Notepad++ by changing the Encoding from ANSI to UTF-8.

So far, I have this solution in JS (client side), but I don't like to use the `escape()` function and would like to do the fix on server side.

```
var badString = "AdriÃ¡n JosÃ©";
var fixedString = decodeURIComponent(escape(badString)); // "Adrián José"
```

I tried to play with the Encoding class in C# ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922199/c-sharp-convert-string-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-latin1-h)), but couln't find a valid combination.

```
var badString = "AdriÃ¡n JosÃ©";
var origEnco = Encoding.UTF8;
var targetEnco = Encoding.Default;
byte[] utfBytes = origEnco.GetBytes(badString);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(origEnco, targetEnco, utfBytes);
string fixedString = targetEnco.GetString(isoBytes); // "AdriÃ¡n JosÃ©"
```

What am I missing? How do the character set fixer or Notepad++ work?

Comment: Do you know the wrong encoding that was used to produce the string you are getting? And do you know the *correct* encoding that should be used to decode the string?

Comment: How are you obtaining the string in the first place? Could it be that that's where the problem lies? One scenario I can imagine: using HttpClient's `.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` when the content isn't UTF8-encoded.

Comment: You may need to loop through all possible *pairs* of encodings to figure out how to reconstruct the string.  Take a look at the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39510190/3744182) to [filter invalid values in json string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39509138/3744182) for an example.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. I don't know the actual encoding of the string in the DB (inside a JSON). I also tried the suggested loop before you provided the final solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your provided example, this code works and outputs "Adrián José" as expected:

```cs
var currentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
var targetEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string input = "AdriÃ¡n JosÃ©";
string output = targetEncoding.GetString(currentEncoding.GetBytes(input));
```

If you're using .NET Core/.NET 5+ then you'll need to install `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` from NuGet and add this somewhere in your code (I usually do it at the top of my Main method):

```cs
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

While this provides the result you're interested in, I don't know if it will work for all instances of your bad text.

If you can, I would fix the problem at the source, rather than trying to fix it once you have the incorrectly-encoded string.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was a little upset for not finding a solution for a relatively simple problem.
It seems I didn't need to call the Convert function in this case.